# Is it normal that compiling with intel fortran is very slow. How to fix the slow compiling issue?

Tags: compilation, intel-fortran

Compiling with intel fortran seems very slow. How to fix the slow compiling issue? It is much slower than gfortran on my computer.

I did some google search, but did not find any relevant information about compiling comparison between intel fortran and gfortran.

Comment: Have you checked how much memory it is trying to use, and whether your machine has that much?

Comment: What exact compiler flags are you using? For both compilers. Show us your compiler commands and their durations. I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: In the past I hit a problem where some specific code was beimg compiled extremely slowly due to a bug in the compiler. However, that was a problem that appeared for that specific piece of code and the specific code was necessary for diagnosis. We have to know what exactly you are doing. In detail.

Comment: How big is the code? I did have this once, and split out the functions and subroutines into separate modules, and they were about 30k lines in total. If most of the heavy lifting is in a library, then it often will not need to be recompiled as often as the program that is using the library.